# Spark Timestamp Column Not Serializable Error

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a proof-of-concept application that modifies a DataFrame by adding a timestamp column, like so:

```
val modified = source.withColumn("time_stamp", current_timestamp().as("time_stamp"))
modified.show()
```

However, it throws an error on the second line:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:231)
at
(yadda, yadda, yadda) 
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Failed to serialize task 80, not attempting to retry it. Exception during serialization: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, value: current_timestamp())
    - element of array (index: 6)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 7)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow, name: values, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow, [1,1,like right now,system,no really, like just now,system,current_timestamp()])
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Lorg.apache.spark.sql.Row;, size 1)
    - field (class: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef, name: array, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef, WrappedArray([1,1,like right now,system,no really, like just now,system,current_timestamp()]))
    - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition, org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition@a47)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask, name: partition, type: interface org.apache.spark.Partition)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask, ShuffleMapTask(24, 7))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think this error has anything to do with your piece of code. your code is good, how are you initializing your spark context ?

Comment: `    def getSparkSession():SparkSession = {
        val session = SparkSession.builder()
              .appName("Hello World")
              .master("local[*]")
              .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0") 
              .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") 
              .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") 
              .config("spark.databricks.io.parquet.nativeReader.enabled", false)  
              .getOrCreate()`